# IIS URL Rewrite for multiple domains

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I am very poor with REGEX and need some help. I have multiple domains hosted on one site e.g. companya.com, companya.cn, companya.fr etc. Based on the host name I would like to redirect them to a subdirectory.  So if someone goes to companya.com it would go to companya.com/en-us/default.aspx and if they went to companya.cn it would go to companya.cn/zh-cn/default.aspx.

Can someone help me please come up with a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd need a regex for this. You can probably just store country codes in a simple dictionary/hash/whatever it's called in the language you're using. In pseudocode:

```
country_codes=\
{
    "com":"en-us",\
    "cn":"zh-cn",\
    "fr":"fr-fr"\
    //similar entries for other country codes go here
};
redirect("companya."+tld+"/"+country_codes[tld]+"/default.aspx");
```